# Matrix contains unexpected null values

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to create a multidimensional array that contains each value of each column in each row's data. Firstly I make an empty global array to store the values. Then I fill the array with the data using looping with for then print the array to make sure that it shows what it's supposed to store but somehow it also stores empty values. This maybe because I declare an empty array in the first place. I need it to only contain the values from my table which has n-rows and 4-columns. The connection is correct I already checked it and I think it has something to do with the loop or maybe the empty array variable.

```
//this is the code
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
function proses_saw(){
    include 'koneksi.php';
    $matrix = array();
    $data = mysqli_query($koneksi,"SELECT * FROM konversi WHERE NIM");
    $rowcount = mysqli_num_rows($data);
    $culcount = mysqli_field_count($koneksi);
    $culcount = $culcount - 2;
    printf($rowcount);
    printf($culcount);
    echo "<br/>";
    for ($row = 0; $row < $rowcount; $row++) {
    for ($col = 0; $col < $culcount; $col++) {
        $d = mysqli_fetch_array($data);
        echo "<br/>";
        global $matrix;
        $matrix = array($d['ip'],$d['kt'],$d['prestasi'],$d['pb']);
        print_r($GLOBALS['matrix']);    
        }//end of for column
    }//end of for rows
} //end of function

?>
</body>
</html>
```

```
//this is what it shows
Array ( [0] => 5 [1] => 1 [2] => 1 [3] => 2 )
Array ( [0] => 4 [1] => 3 [2] => 3 [3] => 2 )
Array ( [0] => [1] => [2] => [3] => )
Array ( [0] => [1] => [2] => [3] => )
Array ( [0] => [1] => [2] => [3] => )
Array ( [0] => [1] => [2] => [3] => )
Array ( [0] => [1] => [2] => [3] => )
Array ( [0] => [1] => [2] => [3] => )
```

Comment: Why `global $matrix; ....; print_r($GLOBALS['matrix']);`instead of `print_r($matrix)` ?

Comment: because i thought its how we call global variable? anyway, i ```print_r($matrix)``` this doesn't change the result

Comment: yes, thank you for telling me my mistake and correcting it @DimitrisFilippou i understand it now, thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your inner loop on `$col` is not necessary. Each call to `mysqli_fetch_array` fetches a whole row, not a column at a time. In fact, you should just loop on the status of `mysqli_fetch_array`; there's no need to use `$rowcount` or `$colcount` at all. Also, you have already declared `$matrix`, there is no need to declare it again. Finally, each pass through the loop is overwriting the value in `$matrix`, when you probably want to add rows to the array. Try this:

```
while ($d = mysqli_fetch_array($data)) {
    echo "<br/>";
    print_r($d);    
    $matrix[] = array($d['ip'],$d['kt'],$d['prestasi'],$d['pb']);
} //end of while rows
```

After this loop `$matrix` will contain (based on your output above)

```
Array (
    [0] => Array ( [0] => 5 [1] => 1 [2] => 1 [3] => 2 )
    [1] => Array ( [0] => 4 [1] => 3 [2] => 3 [3] => 2 )
)
```

At this point you will probably want to return `$matrix` from your function with

```
return $matrix;
```

Comment: thanks Nick, it worked. i thought inner loop is needed when i want to make multidimensional array. and i thought the ```$rowcount``` is needed as limit in the for loop. thank you for explaining my mistakes and the solution Nick :)